# Script fails to find or execute folder file

Tags: php, html

I'm transferring my website from a server that was hosted locally to a actual webhost. But our php script that is supposed to load small html documents doesn't work now.

I've tried contacting the webhost support, but they couldn't really help me.
I've tried different paths to the script or folder with the html documents.
I've tried setting all the scripts and folders to use '755'
I've tried different browsers.

newspage.php is located in the same folder as index.php where newspage.php is called from.

index.php

```
<div class="content" >
  <?php include_once ('newspage.php'); ?>
</div>
```

'Nieuws' is the folder with the html documents in it, they are titled 1 to 5.

Here is one as an example

1.html

```
<div id="news-module">
<header>
    <div id="spawn4" class="resize">
        Vaderdag 2018
    </div>
<p class="no-text-shadow">11-12-17</p>
</header>

    <div id="news4" aria-expanded="false">
        <p class="news">Vooraf via Pin betalen.<br> Geldig vanaf vandaag t.m 18 juni 2018</p>
            <div>
                <img src="/images/nieuws/Image1527534901002.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;" alt="Vaderdag" title="">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

newspage.php

```
<?php
$selectedindex = 0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['newsitem'])){
    $selectedindex = $_REQUEST['newsitem'];
}
# $goedepath = "/var/www/html/Hielo-website/Nieuws"; #
$goedepath = "Nieuws";


$txt =  explode("\n",shell_exec("ls  -r -a -1 $goedepath "));
$ttip = 0;
$maxheight = "285px";
echo "
    <div style='position: relative;'>
        <button class='button date alt' style='margin-bottom:5px; font-size:25px; line-height:25px;' onclick='alpha()' id='vorige'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></button>
        <button style='position: absolute; right: 0px; font-size:25px; line-height:25px;' class='button date alt' onclick='beta()' id='volgende'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></button>
    </div>";
foreach($txt as $bestand){
    $tty = "$goedepath/$bestand";
    if(file_exists($tty)){
        echo "<div id='dx$ttip' style='display: none; min-height: $maxheight; max-height: $maxheight;'>" . file_get_contents($tty) . "</div>";
        $ttip = $ttip + 1;
    }
}
echo "
<button onclick='toggleMoreOrLess()' class='expandnewsbutton' id='readmorebutton' style='display: none'>Lees meer</button>
<div id='emptynewsspace' style='display: block; height: 51px; width: auto;'></div>
<script>

function toggleMoreOrLess(){
    var element = document.getElementById('dx'+XxX);
    var gevraagd = element.scrollHeight+'px';
    var minimaal = '$maxheight';
    if(element.style.maxHeight==minimaal){
        element.style.maxHeight = gevraagd;
        readmorebutton.innerHTML = 'Lees minder';
    }else{
        element.style.maxHeight = minimaal;
        readmorebutton.innerHTML = 'Lees meer';
    }
}

var XxX = 0;

function alpha(){
    resetStatement();
    XxX--;
    gamma();
}

function beta(){
    resetStatement();
    XxX++;
    gamma();
}

function resetStatement(){
    var minimaal = '$maxheight';
    var actueelActiefDocument = document.getElementById('dx'+XxX);
    actueelActiefDocument.style.maxHeight = minimaal;
    readmorebutton.innerHTML = 'Lees meer';
}

function gamma(){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < $ttip ; i++){
        document.getElementById('dx'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
    var element = document.getElementById('dx'+XxX);
    element.style.display = 'block';
    element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
        element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
        // your element have overflow
        readmorebutton.style.display = 'block';
        emptynewsspace.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        // your element doesn't have overflow
        readmorebutton.style.display = 'none';
        emptynewsspace.style.display = 'block';
    }
    vorige.disabled = XxX==0;
    volgende.disabled = XxX==($ttip-4);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){gamma()}, false );

</script>

";
?>
```

It's supposed to load the html documents and display them one at a time. Whereas if you hit the prev/next button it will display the previous or next document.

What actually happens is that it doesn't show any of the files. And if i inspect it, its showing me this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
        <button class="button date alt" style="margin-bottom:5px; font-size:25px; line-height:25px;" onclick="alpha()" id="vorige" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
        <button style="position: absolute; right: 0px; font-size:25px; line-height:25px;" class="button date alt" onclick="beta()" id="volgende"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    </div>

<div id="dx0" style="display: block; min-height: 285px; max-height: 285px; overflow: hidden;"></div>

<button onclick="toggleMoreOrLess()" class="expandnewsbutton" id="readmorebutton" style="display: none">Lees meer</button>

<div id="emptynewsspace" style="display: block; height: 51px; width: auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have the permission to execute shell_exec() commands ? It can be disabled for security reason.
Alternatively, you can use `scandir()` to list the files of a directory

Comment: I'm not sure if I have permission. But php safemode is off according to the host. Which can block it i think. Also how do i go about using scandir? I've tried replacing shell_exec with it, but still nothing happens. In fact it does even less now. Before it would display the div "id=dx0" but now nothing.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure its off anymore. If its on then I can't change it.

Comment: `scandir($goedepath);` will return you a array with the files present in the directory. No need to execute a shell script and then parse the output of `ls`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: Got it working now, thanks. Its not working 100% right though. But it never was. I don't suppose you would want to help me with this? Or do I have to create a new question for this? For some reason there are always empty pages created, after a couple of real ones. And it has a hard limit to how many pages you can click next on. That's the ```$ttip-4``` at the end. I would like to keep a limit, but i also have a page where all news items are on, so i would like to remove the limit without it breaking. If i set it to 0, you can forever click next, but if you run out of items you cant go back.